# Covering map of the universal cover $\widetilde{G} \rightarrow G$ for $G$ a Lie group is a homomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

In a paper I'm reading, we have a compact Lie group $G$ and he says "We can identify $\pi_1(G)$ with the kernel of $\widetilde{G} \rightarrow G$.

I can't seem to find anything that says that the covering map for the universal cover of a Lie group is a homomorphism. The statement doesn't make sense to me if it's not a homomorphism, however. If it's not a homomorphism, what does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a connected Lie group, then $\tilde G$ (the universal covering of $G$) is a simply connected manifild. But it is not a Lie group. One must define there a groups structuro. But, if $p\colon\tilde G\longrightarrow G$ is the covering map and if you fix some element $\tilde e$ of $p^{-1}(e)$, then there is one and only one group structure on $\tilde G$ such that $\tilde e$ is the identity element of $\tilde G$ and that $p$ is a group homomorphism. With respect with this group structure, yes, $\tilde G$ is a Lie group. Furthermore, is $\tilde e'$ is another element of $p^{-1}(e)$, then $\tilde G$ endowed with these group structures (the one induced by $\tilde e$ and the one induced by $\tilde e'$) is twice the same group (in the sense that there is a group isomorphism between $\tilde G$ endowed with the first group structure and $\tilde G$ endowed with the second one).

Comment: For $G$ connected do you define $\bar{G}$ as the set of homotopy classes of curves $\gamma  \subset G$ modulo the equivalence $g \gamma \simeq \gamma $ for $g \in G$ and the group law given by concatenation of curves whose endpoints fit ? If $\gamma,\beta$ are contained in a simply connected neighborhood of $1$ it coincides with the group law on $G$, since then the curves are uniquely defined by their endpoints and $(1 \to a).( 1 \to b) = \cases{(1 \to a).(a \to ab) = (1 \to ab)\\  (a^{-1} \to 1).( 1 \to b) = (a^{-1} \to b)= (1 \to ab)}$

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of $\tilde G$ that I use.